# Angular preventDefault() causing unwanted blur/digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

All,

In my Angular (1.5.9) SPA, I have a model where the user selects from a dropdown list and an element is rendered based upon the selection them make. This works, however when the user interacts with the rendered element (an input field), angular performs a digest and the element blurs - due to re-rendering I assume.

This happens in a bootstrap modal window, and strangely I don't encounter this issue in another part of my application where something similar happens. I'll provide the view below.

Using Batarang, I can see that a digest is occurring when I focus on an input, but I can't explain *why*.

```
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
   <button id="btn-append-to-single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
                        Select Field <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <li ng-show="!field.bolIsPrimaryKey" 
          ng-repeat="field in fields()">
         <a href="#" ng-click="displayColumn(field, $event)">     
            {{field.strColumnAlias}}
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<div ng-repeat="field in fields() track by $index">
  <div ng-show="field.visible">
    <!-- free text field -->
    <div ng-if="field.objDataType == 0">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="text" ng-model="field.objNewRowValue" required>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have found that in order to keep focus whilst interacting with the input, I need to hold mouseclick down and then type.

**Update**

I have found that my issue lies in passing in `$event` into my button onclick and calling `$event.preventDefault();` inside the function. If I remove the dropdown, and simply display every object in the array within the view, I don't encounter such problems. I've included the function below.

```
$scope.displayColumn = function (col, $event) {
   $event.preventDefault();
    angular.forEach($scope.fields(), function (field) {
        if (field.strColumnName === col.strColumnName) {
            field.visible = true;
        } else {
            field.visible = false;
        };
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that preventing propagation on each rendered input resolves the issue I was experiencing. However, I cannot explain why this resolves the issue, however...

I added this function to my controller

```
$scope.stopProp = function (event){
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```

And to each rendered input, I modified my view so to mimic the following

```
<div ng-if="field.objDataType == 0">
    <label>
        {{field.strColumnAlias}}
    </label>
    <input type="text" ng-click="stopProp($event)" 
                       class="form-control" 
                       name="text" 
                       ng-model="field.objNewRowValue" 
                       placeholder="Please enter a {{field.strColumnAlias}}" 
                       required>
</div>
```